# Add a new row to a data.table in R by differencing 2 rows

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table as follows:

```
Month    Portfolio     ExcessReturn
196306   Portfolio 1    -0.303536
196306   Portfolio 10    -1.250765
196307   Portfolio 1     3.2952484
196307   Portfolio 10    6.4787957
```

I want to add a row for each month with the value in portfolio column as portfolio LS and Value in Excess Return columns the the difference in the values between Excess Return of Portfolio 10 and Portfolio 1.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do a group by 'Month', 'Portfolio' (as new value), get the `diff`erence of 'ExcessReturn' to sumnmarise the dataset ('out'), then `rbind` with the original dataset and `order` the 'Month'

```
library(data.table)
out <- setDT(df1)[, .(ExcessReturn = diff(ExcessReturn)),
       .(Month)][, Portfolio  := 'Portfolio LS']
rbind(df1, out)[order(Month)]
```

-output

```
#    Month    Portfolio ExcessReturn
#1: 196306  Portfolio 1    -0.303536
#2: 196306 Portfolio 10    -1.250765
#3: 196306 Portfolio LS    -0.947229
#4: 196307  Portfolio 1     3.295248
#5: 196307 Portfolio 10     6.478796
#6: 196307 Portfolio LS     3.183547
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Month = c(196306L, 196306L, 196307L, 196307L), 
    Portfolio = c("Portfolio 1", "Portfolio 10", "Portfolio 1", 
    "Portfolio 10"), ExcessReturn = c(-0.303536, -1.250765, 3.2952484, 
    6.4787957)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `dplyr`, you can do this as :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Month) %>%
  summarise(ExcessReturn = ExcessReturn[Portfolio == 'Portfolio 10'] - 
                           ExcessReturn[Portfolio == 'Portfolio 1'], 
            Portfolio = 'Portfolio LS') %>%
  bind_rows(df) %>%
  arrange(Month, Portfolio)

#   Month ExcessReturn Portfolio   
#   <int>        <dbl> <chr>       
#1 196306       -0.304 Portfolio 1 
#2 196306       -1.25  Portfolio 10
#3 196306       -0.947 Portfolio LS
#4 196307        3.30  Portfolio 1 
#5 196307        6.48  Portfolio 10
#6 196307        3.18  Portfolio LS
```